# NoSuchMethodError using Kotlin with new Android data binding

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to play with the new Android data binding (https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) in a project using kotlin and it fails on the processing of layout resources:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android-app:dataBindingLayoutsProcessDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.KotlinPackage.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at android.databinding.tool.util.XmlEditor.expressionAttributes(XmlEditor.kt:68)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.XmlEditor.hasExpressionAttributes(XmlEditor.kt:59)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.XmlEditor.recurseReplace(XmlEditor.kt:199)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.XmlEditor.strip(XmlEditor.kt:127)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.stripBindingTags(LayoutFileParser.java:260)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.stripFileAndGetOriginal(LayoutFileParser.java:298)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseXml(LayoutFileParser.java:70)
    at android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.processResources(LayoutXmlProcessor.java:102)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBindingProcessLayoutsTask.doIt(DataBindingProcessLayoutsTask.kt:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Please try new Kotlin: 0.12.613

Comment: That was using 0.12.613

Comment: Please also post your layout file and the model class you are using . I might have an idea how to solve this but need more info.

Comment: This is likely an outdated issue due to older version of Kotlin, or not including all of the Kotlin runtime with the final app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165324/kotlin-android-unresolved-reference-databinding?rq=1