# Kotlin-android: unresolved reference databinding

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have following fragment class written in Java using the new databinding library

```
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentDataBdinding;

public class DataFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    private FragmentDataBinding mBinding;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs fine.
I tried to rewrite it in Kotlin and came up with the following:

```
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentDataBdinding

class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private var mBinding: FragmentDataBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_data, container, false)
        return mBinding!!.getRoot()
    }
}
```

But now step `:app:compileDebugKotlin` outputs the following:

> Error:(16, 38) Unresolved reference: databinding
>   Error:(37, 27) Unresolved reference: FragmentDataBinding

How can I use android-databinding library with Kotlin?

My top-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My `build.gradle` in app dir (only relevant parts):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '0.14.451'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.4, Build tools version 23.0.1, Android SDK 23, SDK tools 24.4.0

Comment: Please, feel free to vote for the corresponding issue: [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8007](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8007)

Comment: You only need to have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in app gradle file in most recent version.

Comment: private lateinit var binding : FragmentDataBinding 
Is a better way of initializing

Answer (score 96):

Try use this configuration:

In main **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '<kotlin-version>'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '2.2.0-alpha4'
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
    //... rest of the content
    }
}
```

App **build.gradle**:

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: @Irampazzo, `2.2.0-alphaX` is available, and FYI the version of data-binding is same as that of android-gradle-plugin itself. so you can externalize that version and use it as the compiler's version.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer fixed my issue with databinding and kotlin

Comment: I had to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` also. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42974558/1916449

Comment: I tried this. Now it gives me a circular dependency error. Any idea about this ?

Comment: Check out https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-frameworks.html#data-binding for official documentation on this.

Comment: correct one, and dont forget to add  :)
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

Comment: I had tried the above and it only worked when restarting Android Studio. Worth trying if you're still not having any luck.

Comment: worked for me except my version is 3.0.0-beta2, be sure to set your version correctly, an sync gradle

Comment: I had to add the following lines too:
`plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Answer (score 92):

I found new solution, hope it will helps you.

First of all check whether plugin applied:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

then

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

You might have an error in dependency:

**USE**

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
```

*instead of*

```
compile 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
```

You can visit [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.databinding/compiler?repo=google) for new version

Thank you.

And use layout tags in layout file before using its binding class , you can easily do that :
In layout file your root view (e.g.- Constraint Layout) ALT+Enter ->  convert to data binding class

Comment: I still have this problem :(

Comment: This is working for me (gradle wrapper 4.4, tools 3.1.0)

Comment: Adding kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1' works for me

Comment: It worked for me by adding only "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt". Thanks.

Comment: just added this line is working for me (apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt')
Android Studio 3.2.1 - Kotlin plugin 1.3.0

Comment: **com.android.databinding:compiler** is not needed

Comment: The last piece was what worked for me, specifically: **"And use layout tags in layout file before using its binding class , you can easily do that : In layout file your root view (e.g.- Constraint Layout) ALT+Enter -> convert to data binding class"**. After doing that I was given the option to import the binding in the code-behind Kotlin class.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, this solved my problem.

I added this in the app build.gradle:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
    viewBinding true 
}
```

Comment: "viewBinding true " worked for me.. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

### Update 2: This is a really old answer, instead refer to lrampazzo's answer.

It works with 1.0-rc4, put

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc4'
```

into your dependencies

Thanks Ghedeon, for the link in comments

**Update**: [Here's](https://github.com/jaydeep17/KotlinDataBinding) a really simple hello world example project

Comment: I still get the same error, am i doing something wrong here? https://gist.github.com/xdgimf/820c433efa8307821788

Comment: here's my build.gradle file if you need a reference https://gist.github.com/jaydeep17/9960fdb0e5a1ba85e82d

Comment: @Jaydeep Have just tried it, and it's working. However Android studio doesn't highlight syntax and generates lots of IDE errors with message `Exception while analyzing expression at (12,23) in /projectpath/KotlinDataBinding/app/src/main/java/com/example/kotlindatabinding/MainActivity.kt:`. Do you have the same errors? And what's your android studio version?

Comment: @Arkadiy It's already been reported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8007 BTW I'm on studio v1.5 Preview 2

Comment: This is no longer the latest version of the plugin. It'll cause unnecessary pain.

Comment: It didn't work for me without the `kapt { generateStubs = true }` in there as well. Please update your answer. Also note of the latest comment by Avinash R: `1.0-rc4` is no longer the latest version of the plugin.

Comment: I had to add apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Comment: Voted up for the direction mentioning this one as an 'Old answer'. Thoughtful and Helpful!

Answer (score 13):

The version of Data Binding compiler is same as gradle version in your project build.gradle file:

```
// at the top of file 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
  dataBinding.enabled = true
}

dependencies {
  kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-beta1"
}
```

and the gradle version is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
```

Here is an example link to complete using of databinding library in kotlin.

https://proandroiddev.com/modern-android-development-with-kotlin-september-2017-part-1-f976483f7bd6

Comment: `dataBinding.enabled = true` was what I was forgetting

Answer (score 7):

To Solve the problem, you have to put

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

at the top of build.gradle (Module: app), then put this line in dependencies

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:[YOUR_ANDROID_PLUGIN_VERSION]"
```

You can find android plugin version by go to menu

```
File > Project Structure > Project
```

Then Sync Again. If you see this warning, ignore it.

> 3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause

Answer (score 6):

Try this.Andrid studio 2.0(2.1)

In **build.gradle**

```
android{
   dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
...
}
dependencies {
 kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.0.0-rc1'
....
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

In my project:    `buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"`

in top level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: you should use the same version for both the compiler and the android build tools gradle plugin. Otherwise it can cause unpredictable build issues.

Comment: I had to add apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Answer (score 6):

this work for me in androidStudio ver3.1.3

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

[image: show usage sample]

Answer (score 5):

In the Gradle module file add this

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

To use databinding in Kotlin you need to configure your app to use data binding, enable the dataBinding build option in your build.gradle file in the .app module and you can replace your code with this:

```
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentDataBdinding

class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateint var mBinding: FragmentProfileBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_data, container, false)

        return mBinding.getRoot()
    }
}
```

For more help check the databinding documentation link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding.

Answer (score 4):

Configuration data binding in kotlin

**build.gradle (folder app)**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
   ...
   dataBinding {
      enabled = true
   }
}

dependencies {
   // data binding
   kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.3"
}
```

Enjoy Kotlin...

Comment: apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' is really important in Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

## Important Update

You can see in [documentation of Android.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start)

> The new compiler in version 3.2 is enabled by default.

So **Just Update** your **Android Studio to V3.2** or [newer](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/). and remove all unnecessary config.

### So just enable dataBinding in app level `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

It will do all things for you automatically.

#### You can SAFELY REMOVE below lines-

- Remove **databinding.compiler**

  ```
  kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'
  ```
- Remove `kapt`

  ```
  kapt {
      generateStubs = true
  }
  ```

### My complete config

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
kotlin_version = '1.2.71'    
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Use [gradle latest version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).
Use [kotlin latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52585894/6891563).

**build.gradle (App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

**Important** Do not just copy and paste config. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52585894/6891563) for setting up Kotlin version.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: My project is still on gradle 3.0.1 release so this didn't work for me.

Comment: You can update your Android Studio and gradle to achieve more stability.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the error was `Unresolved reference: RegisterationUserBinding` I just used my layout name `fragment_registeration_user` like this `FragmentRegisterationUserBinding` and made it in the Databinding layout and the error went away.

Comment: You are great! I spent a lot of time to apply multiple suggestions to resolve the issue but helpless till found this answer. Changing the binding according to fragment layout name resolves the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad it helped you

Answer (score 4):

Add below build features in your app `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
  buildFeatures {
      viewBinding true
  }
}
```

Then in your activity `onCreate` method:

```kotlin
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your **gradle.properties**

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following in you `app build.gradle`

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // This one at top where plugin belong to
```

This will do the trick.

`$android_plugin_version` is version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` in `application build.gradle`

Also, add this to your module `build.gradle`

`android {
    /// Existing Code
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

In your Gradle module (app) file add

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

**BTW, keep in mind: Generated view binding name is based on name of your layout file, NOT on name of your class!**

That means, if you have `MainActivity` class with corresponding `activity_main.xml`, the binding will be called `ActivityMainBinding`.

Also, do not forget to initialize your `binding` variable by adding

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

into your `onCreate()` method.

Do not forget to add this as well:

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

instead of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` (that would cause your listeners to not work at all)

Answer (score 0):

Add Databinding in android Project using when you have use kotlin language.

**Below steps**

--First you need to add the below plugin

```
**apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'**
```

--Second dataBinding enabled true

```
**dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }**
```

All this point added in app.build.gradle
after hit "SYNC NOW"

Lets For example you have edit profile activity then how to define binding variable in kotlin??

```
lateinit var buildProfileBinding: ActivityBuildProfileBinding

buildProfileBinding = getBinding()
```

Here,get binding is method to handle which type of binding object

```
protected <T extends ViewDataBinding> T getBinding() {
                return (T) binding;
            }
```

Comment: DataBinding Librabry 


kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.1'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Solved the problem for me. I ignored it the first time, I thought it's irrelevant to the problem:

> Unresolved reference databinding

But now, data-binding is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my own expirience. To use data databinding with Kotlin in android studio is enough to add

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

After that "sync it" and, it's very important, to  "make Project". After that all your object will be active to use.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to use FragmentDetailsBinding you have to make sure you converted the corresponding layout( fragment_details.xml  ) to data binding layout by wrapping the whole layout in "" tag parent and move all of xmlns to layout tag then build the project and thats it

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only forgot to add in layout file the header:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in this post and other parts of the internet but continued with the problem. Finally figured out that the folder name was too long, and when I built the app this "unresolved reference databinding" error appeared, but there was nothing on logcat about long name folders. I was about to give up when for some reason I tried moving the project to the desktop and inside a short name folder and problem solved!

So if your project is inside a destination like this:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Udemy\Kotlin courses\2023\...very long name folder and very nested...\databindingProject
```

Just move it to:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Kotlin courses\databindingProject
```

Open it and it should build. If not try invalidate caches and restart.

But what caused it? I think that when Android Studio do the build process it generates a lot of files and maybe because of the long name folders and the folders nested inside other folders, some files are not created because Windows doesn't allow it, and that causes the error at the end.