# How to bind onClick event from view using Android Binding Library and Kotlin?

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm struggling to make [Android Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) to work with Kotlin. What I want to achieve is dispatch a onClick event to my Presenter class. What I've done was:

1. Enable databinding on module's gradle file: `dataBinding {enabled = true}`
2. Import databinding compiler: `kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.0.0-beta6'`
3. Generate stubs: `kapt {generateStubs = true}`
4. Implement method on MainPresenter.kt:

   ```
   fun onClickEditProfile () {
       log("method you hoped to get called was called")
       mView!!.getContext().snackbar("received event: onClickEditProfile via data binding, this is awesome").show()
   }
   ```
5. Prepare layout:

   ```
   <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <data>
           <variable
               name="presenter"
               type="br.com.tyllt.presenter.MainPresenter" />
       </data>
           <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onClickEditProfile()}"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
               app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
               app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
               app:fab_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_scale_down"
               app:fab_label="Edit Profile"
               app:fab_size="mini" />
   </layout>
   ```

Problem is, when I generate the apk I get the followin exception:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.jetbrains.kotlin.annotation.RoundEnvironmentWrapper.getElementsAnnotatedWith, parameter a

Any idea?

Comment: Paste your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Well, after following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044756/2068693) answer and taking care to use:

```
private fun initDataBinding() {
        val binding: ActivityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login)
        binding.presenter = mPresenter
    }
```

I was able to make it work. The problem was, I was initing the binding only using:

```
MainActivityBinding binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
```

As pointed on [Data Binding Library official page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html), which by some reason didnt work for me.