# How to use lombok with Kapt3

Tags: java, android, data-binding, kotlin, lombok

When I try to run Java/Kotlin android application with Lombok while using Kapt3:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

javac compilation fails with numerous

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

for generated methods.

It is probably caused by inability of kapt to generate stubs:

```
  'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
```

All aforementioned forces me to use older kapt where I can use:

```
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVer"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVer"
kapt "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVer"

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

This however results in fail during test compilation, because I am also using databinding library:

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileXDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse data binding compiler options. Params:
>     kapt.annotations : ...\app\build\tmp\kapt\xDebugUnitTest\wrappers\annotations.bscplayDebugUnitTest.txt
>     kapt.kotlin.generated : ...\app\build\tmp\kapt\xDebugUnitTest\kotlinGenerated

This, on the other hand, forces me to use Kapt3 as described here:
[android databinding unit test error Failed to parse data binding compiler options.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692556/android-databinding-unit-test-error-failed-to-parse-data-binding-compiler-option)

**Does anyone know how to resolve this issue with Lombok?** All I was a hint to use my first solution, but it leads to the databinding problem (as per [Kotlin Support · Issue #1169 · rzwitserloot/lombok · GitHub](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1169))

Note: Situation is same in Android studio 2.3.3 and in Android Studio 3 (with gradle build tools 3.0.0).

Comment: Why do you want to use lombok on kotlin anyway? There's nothing which enhance the code using lombok while using kotlin

Comment: It is actually Java/Kotlin module with a lot of classes still written in Java where Lombok is still used. I of course do not plan to use Lombok when whole project is migrated to Kotlin (which i hope will be soon, but scope is huge).

Comment: A "big" project can't be big if there's no time to convert bad patterns/code into good one :)

Comment: All new code is written in kotlin and old code is being migrated on demand as we can't afford to migrate whole project at once (tons of conflicts, maybe some misbehavior). It is better to convert it step by step. Also it is not solely up to me to do such a huge change, there is also rest of the team :)

If it were one of possibilities, i would not even ask such question in the first place :)

Comment: Lombok is usually used to reduce the boilerplate, that means for models.  Using other annotatons can be "faked" if you create them self and use them as proxy for an extension method (like @Log). Models can easy be converted to data classes. Parcels shouldnt be used anyway. But yes, i know what you mean. Anyway, it's better to do that now, then doing that step by step. Had the same sh** in a very large project before :)

Comment: There are, for example, also various view holders nested in java classes which are also utilizing lombok or other nested wrapper classes which would require me to also convert parent class or extract them into new class which i do not want. I deffinitely hope that this conversion will happen fast. There are already few modules which are 100% converted and it works perfectly.
Until then, I would like to resolve this issue somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately, Kotlin is incompatible with Lombok because it uses the private javac API do to its job. Although kapt3 is built on top of the Java compiler, kapt generates Java stubs for Kotlin classes so what can Lombok process is the stubs, not the original classes.

By the way, the original kapt is deprecated and will be removed soon after the Kotlin 1.2 release. So you have some time to migrate to Kotlin & kapt3.

Comment: @yanex Thanks for explanation! Can you please convert this comment to answer so i can accept it and not steal the credit? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was explained by @yanex in comments:

> Unfortunately, Kotlin is incompatible with Lombok because it uses the private javac API do to its job. Although kapt3 is built on top of the Java compiler, kapt generates Java stubs for Kotlin classes so what can Lombok process is the stubs, not the original classes. By the way, the original kapt is deprecated and will be removed soon after the Kotlin 1.2 release. So you have some time to migrate to Kotlin & kapt3.

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle`, add this:

```kotlin
kapt {
    keepJavacAnnotationProcessors = true
}
```

For more info check the [JetBrains Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lombok.html#using-with-kapt)