# kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 instead

Tags: android, kotlin

Yesterday I updated Android Studio Version and Kotlin plugin version.

Android Studio Version: 3.1.2

Kotlin Version: 1.2.41

When I create an Android project using this configuration, I get Kotlin Compiler warning saying

> w: /home/ganeshtikone/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.2.41/9e7a6f582de73d9cdc6c56ef4e23604a0ee55768/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.2.41.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 instead

Changed as per suggestion, then I am getting following error

> Unexpected inputs: ImmutableJarInput{name=org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.41, file=/home/ganeshtikone/Workspace/May-2018/fhs/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/stage/debug/45.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Go to **Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates** and check for updates
then in your app gradle file replace **jre** with **jdk**

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

##### Update

Newer version is jdk8

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Why not **org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Would you like to answer your comment. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 39):

## Important Update

#### Must check JDK version before setting config

[Kotlin gradle config](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies) page has detailed information about this.

First of all check your kotlin version in gradle file.

> ### if (`kotlin_version == '1.2.x'` ) (Use `jdk` NOT `jre`)

First check your jdk version in **File > Project Structure**.

[image: sc]

Or check in `build.gradle`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

**if (jdk_version == 1.8)**

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

**if (jdk_version == 1.7)**

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

**if (jdk_version is < 1.7)**

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

**else if(NO jdk version is set in Project Structure)**

```
if(Android_Studio_Version < 2.2.1){
   your_jdk_version = 1.7;
}
else {
   your_jdk_version = 1.8;
}
```

**Because Android Studio is bundled with jdk 1.8 [since 2.2.1 version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/).**

> ### 2. else if ( `kotlin_version == '1.1.x'`) (Use jre NOT jdk)

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version" // or jre8
```

#### Update Kotlin Version?

You can update Kotlin version from **Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Updates**

Comment: I am using `jdk8` and latest kotlin version ie. `1.3.11` but still the warning shows .. jre7 is deprecated.. P.S my android studio version is `3.3.0`

Comment: @SantanuSur I am not sure. Perhaps, check if any of your dependency is using that version?

Comment: Yes I am using some open source libs..might be one of'em

Comment: @SantanuSur You can check if there is some update from your libraries.

Answer (score 9):

Something is transitively importing those libraries. Run Gradle task `dependencies` to figure out what.

In my case, it was `io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines:3.5.1`.

If there is no update for the dependency, there is not much you can do about it

Answer (score 7):

After reading [Kotlin Gradle Script](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies) Topic 
I find out that some ponits

> If you're targeting JDK 7 or JDK 8, you can use extended versions of the Kotlin standard library which contain additional extension functions for APIs added in new JDK versions. Instead of kotlin-stdlib, use one of the following dependencies:
>
> compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
>   compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

I used implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8" in my project. I think it's because of compileOptions set in build.graddle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must swap the codes below:

```
     implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

Not jre > jdk

```
     implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change SDK7 to Java SDK8
try this:

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

}