# About Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I just started learning Android studio and I'm in the middle of making a My Profile app.
I've used a relative layout and I can see it in design section but when I install that in my phone it doesn't change, I tried reinstalling.
And also it says this

> C:\Users\SHARVARI.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jre7\1.2.50\ba99c630feafe4570da49277ca8bf3c7f71cb6aa\kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.2.50.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 instead

After rebuilding and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself told you to use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7. If you don't know how to do that see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344635/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-is-deprecated-please-use-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-instead)