# How to change JRE to JDK8 in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

On the project I'm working I'm getting the following error and I don't know how to change from JRE to JDK on Android Studio.

```
.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jre8\1.2.20\f77d7863695e17041b50ebe5e2f87e5314a2c812\kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.20.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre8 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 instead
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344635/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-is-deprecated-please-use-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-instead 
 It is a duplicate question as above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the dependency from

```
implementation'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.61'
```

to

```
implementation'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.61'
```