# Android data binding class is not generated in my new module

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-module

I added a module to my project and now I want to put there some fragments.

In my fragment I initialize data binding like this

```
class MyTestFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: 
    MyTestFragmentNewBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_test_fragment_new, container, false)

        binding.test = DataModel("zzz")
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Then in Android Studio I click `make module` and it compiles. After it I try to run my app and see two errors
 `Unresolved reference: MyTestFragmentNewBinding` and

```
import com.example.common.databinding.MyTestFragmentNewBinding
```

I see `Unresolved reference: databinding` I tried a lot of solutions like rebuilding, invalidating cache, closing and reopening Android Studio, nothing works. 
The most interesting thing is that after renaming of layout.xml and after importing new reference to a binding class it works till the next build. Than the same issue.

Did someone have something like this? What can be wrong? It seems that in my second module probably something delete binding class during build or something like this

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563

Comment: Did you add  <layout> tag in XML files @Vitalii

Answer (score 1):

seem likes android studio bugs. Try to rename the layout file name and rebuild the module.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165324/kotlin-android-unresolved-reference-databinding) thread I found the forgotten part that was already present in my main project.

Remember, to enable databinding you need to add

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

to your `build.gradle` file but if you use `Kotlin` don't forget to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

plugin too to your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
       ... 
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't help me in Android Studio 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

After losing an hour scouring through all the possible reasons why this is not working for me, I found out that I made a simple mistake...

instead of:

```
    dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

I had:

```
    dataBinding {
    true
}
```

It was a silly mistake.
Hope that someone will find it useful.